# Can I make an onchain program using JavaScript/TypeScript?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust, token, js

Is there a way to write up and deploy a smart contract using JS instead of Rust for my custom token?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Not yet**.

There is no way you can use javascript at the moment that I'm aware of and I would recommend Rust/Anchor. However if you prefer a different language you can:

- Wait for something called Poseidon coming soon.
- Use [Seahorse](https://seahorse-lang.org/) for Python
- [Solang](https://solana.com/developers/guides/solang/getting-started) for Solidity
- [C/C++](https://docs.solana.com/developing/on-chain-programs/developing-c).

Comment: OK thanks for your help

Comment: You're welcome! :)